# Assign column names to several objects at a time

Tags: r

Must be easy, but I couldn't find a solution...

I have 10 matrices with same dimensions whose names share the pattern "daily_". I want to name the columns of all the objects like this: 0,1,2...10. I tried this:

```
colnames(ls(pat="daily_"))<-c(0:10)
```

But doesn't work! I also tried with a loop but I don't think this is the correct way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off collecting `daily_1` `..._2` etc into a `list` object, but you can reassign these to the global working environment as a roundabout method of getting what you want:

```
daily_1 <- matrix(1:10,ncol=10)
daily_2 <- matrix(1:10,ncol=10)

daily_list <- mget(ls(pattern="daily_"))
daily_list <- lapply(daily_list,`colnames<-`,1:10)
list2env(daily_list,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, without making everything into a list:

```
for(name in ls(pat="daily_")){
   mat <- mget(name)[[1]]
   colnames(mat) <- 1:10
   assign(value=mat, x=name)
}
```

cheers
- h